# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I am new to EJB. My manager told me to deploy an ejb application in our test server for some modification. The application is already running in our production server. But when I deploy the application, I am getting an exception.

we are using Glassfish Application Server

Stack Trace of Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:130)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:149)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:84)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.loadPersistenceUnits(AbstractLoader.java:915)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.doLoad(ApplicationLoader.java:184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:126)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.doLoad(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:240)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:336)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:210)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:645)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeApplicationDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:959)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleApplicationDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:943)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:467)  
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:609)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.start(PEDeploymentService.java:653)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.mbeans.ApplicationsConfigMBean.start(ApplicationsConfigMBean.java:773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:390)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.MBeanHelper.invokeOperationInBean(MBeanHelper.java:373)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.config.BaseConfigMBean.invoke(BaseConfigMBean.java:477)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:857)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:795)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.proxy.ProxyClass.invoke(ProxyClass.java:90)
    at $Proxy1.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.SunoneInterceptor.invoke(SunoneInterceptor.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.client.DeploymentClientUtils.startApplication(DeploymentClientUtils.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.client.DeployAction.run(DeployAction.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

When I restarted the server I am getting these:

```
Unexpected error occurred while loading applications  
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at com.sun.appserv.server.util.ASURLClassLoader.loadClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:130)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:149)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:84)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.loadPersistenceUnits(AbstractLoader.java:915)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.doLoad(ApplicationLoader.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:126)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.doLoad(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.load(AbstractManager.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLifecycle.onStartup(ApplicationLifecycle.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
```

Here also you can see the same problem `at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:107)`

Could anyone **please** help me why this error is coming.
It is very much needed.

Thanks

Comment: Check if the file `hibernate-entitymanager.jar` is there in your classpath.

Comment: You should provide the complete exception. I think there is the cause missing.

Comment: @SirRotN I have updated the complete exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved.
Actually `hibernate-annotations.jar` file was of different version in the server's `lib` folder.
Someone might have changed it. Now its working properly.

Thank You.

Comment: hibernate -annotation.jar and hibernate-common-annotation.jar are different? i included hibernate-common-annotation.jar but i still getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration. i am using hibernate with jpa specification