# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13

Tags: java, maven, jersey, struts, tomcat8

I am new to jersey I made a website which is mostly static except the contact us part which is using `javamail api` and `recaptcha` feature. My project is working fine in eclipse. But when I uploaded it in the production I am facing this issue. It say's the could not initialize class `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13` . I tried various solutions but the thing is that my application is working as expected in test environment (eclipse) but giving exception in production environment.
Here is the stack trace:

[image: Stack trace]
[image: error from production]

Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e194 -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>co.in.****</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Form

```html
 <form class="form" action="webresources/check/validate" name="contactus" method="get">
          <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name = "name" id="name" required="required">
          <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
          <input class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone No:" name="phone" id="phone">
          <textarea class="message" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" required="required"></textarea>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*************"></div>
          <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
         </form>
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.in.******</groupId>
    <artifactId>meshtechnologies</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>**** Jersey Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>*****</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>D:/Projects/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcaptcha-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
        <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Class

```
package co.in.******;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

/** Example resource class hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
 */

@Path("/check")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/validate")
    public Response getData(@QueryParam("name") String name,@QueryParam("email") String email,
            @QueryParam("message") String msg, @QueryParam("phone") String mob
            ,@QueryParam("g-recaptcha-response") String gRecaptchaResponse) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
    {

        // get reCAPTCHA request param

        System.out.println(gRecaptchaResponse);
        boolean verify = VerifyRecaptcha.verify(gRecaptchaResponse);
        if(verify)
        {
            System.out.println("VALID");

            try
            {
              String smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com";
              String to="**********";
              String from= "***************";
              String subject="Contact Request "+email;
              String body= name+" : "+mob+" : "+msg;
              send(smtpServer, to, from, subject, body);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              System.out.println("Usage: java com.lotontech.mail.SimpleSender"
               +" smtpServer toAddress fromAddress subjectText bodyText");
            }

            URI u = new URI("*************");

           return Response.temporaryRedirect(u).build();

        }
        else
        {

            URI u = new URI("*******");
           return Response.temporaryRedirect(u).build();


        }


    }

    protected static void send(String smtpServer, String to, String from
               , String subject, String body)
              {
                try
                {
                  Properties props = System.getProperties();
                  // -- Attaching to default Session, or we could start a new one --
                 props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
                  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                  // -- Create a new message --
                  Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                  // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
                  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
                  // -- We could include CC recipients too --
                  // if (cc != null)
                  // msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC
                  // ,InternetAddress.parse(cc, false));
                  // -- Set the subject and body text --
                  msg.setSubject(subject);
                  msg.setText(body);
                  // -- Set some other header information --
                  msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "LOTONtechEmail");
                  msg.setSentDate(new Date());
                  // -- Send the message --
                //  Transport.send(msg);

                  Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
                  transport.connect(smtpServer, 465, "******","*******");

                  transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                  transport.close();
                  System.out.println("Message sent OK.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                }
              }

}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't even get as far as to load your code. It makes me believe it's related to the server setup. Have you tried deploying a simple "Hello world!" web app?

Comment: Luks like an issue related to [incompatible jar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12226362/452708)

Comment: @MadsNielsen - Yes I have checked with the default hello world provided by jersey it is working fine.

Comment: @Abhijeet - I don't think that it is related to jar issue as the project is working fine in eclipse but I am having issue in production. Secondly I have made a war file and then deployed it in production this means it is using the same jar which it is using at the time of project creation.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with the project itself when I done a clean build for maven then I came to know that the project is not working and I am not getting a fresh copy at the time of writing this question. But  then I made a fresh project and just done a copy paste of my previous data and now it is working fine. I think there was a conflict in the dependencies added.