# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, ejb

I am trying to connect database using Hibernate on Intellij Idea.

Bean file is auto-generated based on Hibernate entity class.

```
public class SirketEntityManagedBean {

    private EntityManagerFactory myEntityManagerFactory;

    public SirketEntityManagedBean() {
        myEntityManagerFactory =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
    }


}
```

Here pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>VPNTest6</groupId>
    <artifactId>VPNTest6</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>VPNTest6</groupId>
            <artifactId>VPNTest6</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//X.XX.XX.XX:1521/PROD</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <mapping class="hib.OrtamEntity"/>
        <mapping class="hib.SorumluEntity"/>
        <mapping class="hib.SirketEntity"/>
        <mapping class="hib.VpnkullaniciEntity"/>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>hib.OrtamEntity</class>
        <class>hib.SorumluEntity</class>
        <class>hib.SirketEntity</class>
        <class>hib.VpnkullaniciEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XX.X.XX.XX:1521/PROD"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="XXTEST"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="XXTEST"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here stackTrace:

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not initialize class
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
>     org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:124)
>     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
>     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>     beans.SirketEntityManagedBean.(SirketEntityManagedBean.java:40)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     org.primefaces.component.panelmenu.PanelMenu.getModel(PanelMenu.java:84)
>     org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:108)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
>     javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:84)
>     org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71)
>     org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

May it be related with naming strategy?
[image: naming_strategy]

Or may it be related with project directory?
Is persistence.xml is in right directory?

[image: proj_dir]

Or is it about hibernate-annotations class?
I have already checked below question and manually added hibernate-annotations jar but did not work.
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215527/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-hibernate-ejb-ejb)

Comment: why post some Hibernate config file if using JPA?

Comment: I have both of them in project.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate API AND JPA API (why ?) then DEFINE which one is being used by your question, and then you can isolate the code to one or the other. AKA Debugging